# parse error jQuery callback on AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I keep receiving a callback error on my AJAX request similar to this one:

```
parsererrorError: jQuery21107497704593028268_1409589069770 was not called [object Object
```

I've tried a variety of approaches but I'm fairly new to jQuery/AJAX.
Here is my request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: DEV_SERVER + "/check_in/add",
    beforeSend: function() {$.mobile.loading('show'); allow_action=false;},
    complete: function() {$.mobile.loading('hide'); allow_action=true;},
    timeout: 10000,
    data: {
        time: timestamp,
        bac: 0.01,
        offender_id: offender_id,
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: lon,
    },
    success: function(data){
        if(data.success){
            // TODO
            alert("success");
        } else {
            // TODO
            alert("error");
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error){
        //TODO
        alert(status + error + jqXHR);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

And on the server side I return with this:

```
$return = $_REQUEST['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($res) . ')';
echo $return;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

what if:

```
 url: DEV_SERVER + "/check_in/add?callback=?"

 $return = $_GET['callback']."('".json_encode($res)."')";
```

and then try some experimental:

```
 $return = '<script>'.$_GET['callback']."('".json_encode($res)."');</script>";
```

Comment: And this $return = $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($res) . ')';

Comment: Still returning a similar parse error and this-- SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

107360738680254322_1409592670289({"success":true})<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: please show var_dump($res); and echo json_encode($res);

Comment: echo json_encode($res) gives this: {"success":true}, echo var_dump($res) gives this: array(1) {
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
}

Comment: this part of your code looks right, just comment // timeout - its not needed, because it hasn't influense on ajax transaction, check what heppens if comment //beforeSend and //complete. Also try another version of jquery, maybe your version have some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of obvious problems here.

In

```
data: {
        time: timestamp,
        bac: 0.01,
        offender_id: offender_id,
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: lon,
    },
```

Remove the comma after `longitude: lon,`

Second, you have said that the returned data will be a JSON data structure `dataType: 'jsonp'` but you are not returning a valid JSON data structure. Try changing the PHP script like this :-

```
// assuming $res is an array
$res['callback'] = $_REQUEST['callback'];

$return = json_encode($res);
echo $return;
```

Now it will probably be a valid JSON structure.

Comment: $res is an array and I'm populating it like this: if ($this->CheckIn->save($_REQUEST) ) {
    $res['success'] = true;
   }else{
    $res['success'] = false;
   }

Answer (score 0):

It is not a valid json which is the obvious issue.

```
$return = $_REQUEST['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($res) . ')';
echo $return;
```

You must return just a json encoded string as output .

Just use:-

```
echo json_encode($res);
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was not disabling the default layout and view in my cakephp code. Adding this "$this->autoRender = false;" as the first line of code in my add() function resolved the issue. I had tried disabling it in the controller previously, but it only needed to be disabled for that function.